# Subgroups of the Dual group $\hat{G}$.

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be finite Abelian group and $\hat{G}=Irr(G)$. Let $H\leq G$. Define 
$$H^{\perp}=\{\ \lambda \in \hat{G} | H\subseteq Ker \lambda \}\ $$

Show that $H^{\perp}$ is a subgroup of $\hat{G}$. Also show that the map $H \to H^{\perp}$ is bijective map between the subgroups of $G$ and $\hat{G}$.

My attempt: I have shown that $H^{\perp}$ is a subgroup of $\hat{G}$. Also I have that $H \subseteq K$ then $K^{\perp} \subseteq H^{\perp}$, i.e, the mapping is inclusing reversing.  But I don't get how to prove that the map is one-one and onto. Also $G \cong \hat{\hat{G}}$ naturally. But I don't get how to use that.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The natural isomorphism $G \cong \widehat{\widehat{G}}$ is given by the map $g \mapsto [\phi_g : \lambda \mapsto \lambda(g)]$. Now the fact that $H \mapsto H^{\perp}$ is injective follows by the fact that $H = H^{\perp\perp}$, which in turn follows by the fact that $\widehat{G/H} \cong H^{\perp}$. For surjectivity, let $A \leq \widehat{G}$. Put $H:=\{ g\in G \mid A \subseteq \text{ker } \phi_g\}.$ Then $H^{\perp} = A$.

$\textbf{NOTE:}$ All the above are hints, and you will have to prove/check them.

Answer (score 0):

You should write that $G$ is finite in your post and not only in tags.

Let $K$ be a subgroup of $G$, let $g$ be in $G$. Let $\xi_g \in \mathbb{U}$ (unit group) have the same order in $\mathbb{U}$ as $gK$ has in $G / K$.

Then the morphism $K + \left\langle g \right\rangle \rightarrow \mathbb{U}$ sending $k.g^n$ to $\xi^n$ has kernel $K$.

Do you see how you can use this to prove the result?